# Row is date, 1st column is name, i want to list out the children who go to school on specific day

Tags: excel

```
      1/10 2/10 3/10 4/10
Peter   Y   Y     Y   N  
John    Y   N     Y   Y
Mary    N   Y     Y   Y
```

E1 is a box to put in the specific date you want to search
F1 and below column can so the ans

Example: `E1 = 4/10`
F1 will show John and G1 will show Mary

How to write this forumla in `F1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the date is in G1, the following formula will give a list of names if it's entered in H1 and pulled across

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(1,(COUNTIF($G1:G1,$A$2:$A$10)=0)*
(INDEX($B$2:$E$10,,MATCH($G$1,$B$1:$E$1,0))="Y"),0)),"")
```

It's an array formula and has to be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

`MATCH($G$1,$B$1:$E$1,0)` gives the number of the column in B2:E10 with the required date

`INDEX($B$2:$E$10,,MATCH($G$1,$B$1:$E$1,0))` gives the contents of the column in B2:E10

`COUNTIF($G1:G1,$A$2:$A$10)=0` checks that the name hasn't been listed yet

`MATCH(1,(COUNTIF($G1:G1,$A$2:$A$10)=0)*(INDEX($B$2:$E$10,,MATCH($G$1,$B$1:$E$1,0))="Y"),0)),"")` gets the position of the next name

`INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(1,(COUNTIF($G1:G1,$A$2:$A$10)=0)*
(INDEX($B$2:$E$10,,MATCH($G$1,$B$1:$E$1,0))="Y"),0))` gets the next name from column A

and `IFERROR` shows an empty cell if there are no more names.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your question!

You can do this pretty simply with an HLOOKUP formula in Excel.  Similar to a VLOOKUP, an HLOOKUP will find a value in a set of columns then return a certain number of rows down.  Below I have included a screenshot of my workbook, with the option to show formulas set to on.

The HLOOKUP function takes the same argument list as VLOOKUP, namely Arg 1 = What value you want to find, in your case the date.  Arg 2 = the cells that contain your data, make sure this includes the date header row as well as all the data rows.  You don't need to get the Name header column, but I don't believe that will break your function in case you do.  Arg 3 = Which row number you want to return once you find a match.  The date header row is row 1, so for Peter you would say Row 2, John Row 3, etc.  The last argument is whether you want an exact match or an approximate match.  I'd recommend setting it to FALSE to tell Excel you want an exact match or none at all.

If you use anchoring on your input cell and your data range, you can drag your formula to all of the children's names.

[HLOOKUP in Practice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x48c.png)

Hope this has helped answer your question! Good luck in your Excel Endeavors!

Comment: The result should be only show who go to school on the day. It is not suitable to write the list again to show y or n, Only names under the date